# Rails - How to change created_at time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
@konkurrencer = Rating.new(params[:kon])
@konkurrencer.save
@konkurrencer.konkurrencer.rating_score += params[:kon][:ratings].to_i
@konkurrencer.konkurrencer.ratings += 1
@konkurrencer.created_at = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
@konkurrencer.save
```

When I create a new item it the created_at column is:

```
2012-02-27 16:35:18
```

I would expect it to be:

```
2012-02-27 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 21):

Your problem is that strftime only formats the time, it doesn't actually change the time.

So when you do Time.now, that returns the time.  Strftime only changes the way that its represented.

If you wanted to change the created_at date to "2012-02-27 00:00:00", just pass that in to `@koncurrencer.created_at`

```
@koncurrencer.created_at = "2012-02-27 00:00:00"
```

That should do it.

In response to your question:

What you were doing should work just fine then. In fact you can just say:

```
@koncurrencer.created_at = Time.now  
@koncurrencer.save
```

and that should work just fine.

If you wanted to always have the time be at the beginning of the day you could use `Date.today` instead of `Time.now` since that always returns the time component of the Date as "00:00:00"

Here is what you want:

```
@koncurrencer.created_at = Date.today  
@koncurrencer.save
```

That should be more clear.

Comment: How to make it dynamic? Like Time.now

Comment: Are you saying you want the date to be dynamic but the time to always be "00:00:00"?

Comment: answered it for you, see my answer.

Comment: Time.now does not make any difference it have hours and seconds.

Comment: Are you saving the @koncurrencer first?  You need to create it, because that will set the created_at date, then update it and save it again.

Comment: I have created it you can see the .save.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the time always to "00:00:00", you can go by this:

```
t = Time.now
=> 2012-02-27 17:46:38 +0100

t2 = Time.parse("00:00:00", t)
=> 2012-02-27 00:00:00 +0100
```